# How can I get an achievementID from an OFAchievement *?

Tags: iphone, openfeint

`[OFAchievement achievements]` returns an NSArray of `OFAchievement *`'s.  OFAchievement has several properties, including title and description but it does not have an acheivementID property.  I could call `[OFAchievement achievement:(NSString *)]` for each of my game's achievements and match up the title, but that seems slow and awkward.

Is there a better way?

Should I just ignore `[OFAchievement achievements]` and only use `[OFAchievement achievement:(NSString *)]` with my own list of achievementIDs?

I am using OpenFeint 2.7.4.